# Accessing XML attributes with namespaces

Tags: xml, scala, parsing

How one can access attributes with namespaces? My XML data are in a form

```
val d = <z:Attachment rdf:about="#item_1"></z:Attachment>
```

but the following does not match the attribute

```
(d \\ "Attachment" \ "@about").toString
```

If I remove the namespace component from the attribute's name then it works.

```
val d = <z:Attachment about="#item_1"></z:Attachment>
(d \\ "Attachment" \ "@about").toString
```

Any idea how to access attributes with namespaces in Scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The API documentation refers to the following syntax `ns \ "@{uri}foo"`.

In your example there is no namespace defined, and it seems Scala considers your attribute as unprefixed. See `d.attributes.getClass`.

Now if you do this:

```
val d = <z:Attachment xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="#item_1"></z:Attachment>
```

Then:

```
scala> d \ "@{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}about"
res21: scala.xml.NodeSeq = #item_1

scala> d.attributes.getClass
res22: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.xml.PrefixedAttribute
```

Answer (score 8):

You can always do

```
d match {
  case xml.Elem(prefix, label, attributes, scope, children@_*) =>
}
```

or in your case also match on `xml.Attribute`

```
d match {
  case xml.Elem(_, "Attachment", xml.Attribute("about", v, _), _, _*) => v
}

// Seq[scala.xml.Node] = #item_1
```

However, `Attribute` does not care about the prefix at all, so if you need that, you need to explicitly use `PrefixedAttribute`:

```
d match {
  case xml.Elem(_, "Attachment", xml.PrefixedAttribute("rdf", "about", v, _), _, _*) => v
}
```

There is a problem, however, when there are multiple attributes. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have

```
val d = <z:Attachment id="foo" rdf:about="#item_1"></z:Attachment>
```

To access the value of an attribute, in [scala-xml](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml) there is

```
d \@ "id"
```

but it doesn't work with namespaces. However, you could add a method that works with namespaces like this:

```
implicit class EasyNode(node: scala.xml.Node):
  def \@@(attributeName: String): String = node.attributes.head.asAttrMap(attributeName)
```

and then use it like that:

```
d \@@ "rdf:about"
```

Works for me.